# I installed Visual Studio Code on Chrome OS, how do I open it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-os

I followed the instructions on https://code.headmelted.com/#chromeos-install-scripts everything went fine.  How do I open it?  I tried 'code' in crosh and got nothing.

Comment: As you probably already know, finding/launching it SHOULD be as simple as clicking on 'Launcher', then clicking the up-arrowhead at top of that panel, and then navigating thru the list of app-icon screens via the vertical group of radio-buttons at on right-side of that screen-panel. (As I recall, they put the most-recently installed app's icon last,  so look in the last group...you'll probably want to "right-click->pin-to-shelf"  on it, once you find it!)  There are other organizing ideas here: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6206362?hl=en

Comment: So, if that's not finding it, I would HAVE to conclude that something went wrong or is incomplete in the app installation, such that it couldn't be put into the installed-app-list at the end of the installation script.  (Figuring out exactly what the error/problem was might involve de-installing and re-installing a few times.)